# Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint Chart - with broken y-Axis

Tags: winforms, powerpoint, winforms-interop

We are using the Interop PowerPoint Chart type to generate an area chart as shown in the figure. We need the "broken" y-Axis. We dont want the break on the bars itself - we need the break only on the y-Axis. But are unable to find a property or a method to achieve this.

This a winforms application. Would really appreciate some pointers...
[image: Chart with broken y-axis]

Comment: You can try to record a macro and look at the generated VBA code. This often leads to the desired APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally stumbled upon this question, and I let my curiosity takes over.
I got how it's done taken from [this site](http://peltiertech.com/broken-y-axis-in-excel-chart/).

I'm using example data from above site for this walkthrough.

The step roughly like this:

1. Assign cut value for data separation. Separate data using a cut value (I use cut value 7,500,000 for the example)

This is data separation from the example (above is the original, below is the separated):

```
                May         June        July
    London      1,234,565   1,452,369   1,478,852
    Paris       2,363,645   34,568,876  5,562,413
    Madrid      32,645,254  3,211,654   5,857,421
    Brussels    5,914,753   5,544,221   3,620,015
    Lisbon      5,824,676   4,541,258   4,015,876
    Munich      2,501,478   6,325,698   4,569,872

                May         June        July        Column4     Column5     Column6
    London      1,234,565   1,452,369   1,478,852   0           0           0
    Paris       2,363,645   7,500,000   5,562,413   0           34,568,876  0
    Madrid      7,500,000   3,211,654   5,857,421   32,645,254  0           0
    Brussels    5,914,753   5,544,221   3,620,015   0           0           0
    Lisbon      5,824,676   4,541,258   4,015,876   0           0           0
    Munich      2,501,478   6,325,698   4,569,872   0           0           0
```

2. Assign `Column4`, `Column5`, and `Column6` into secondary axis.

   ```
   Dim c As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Chart
   Dim sc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SeriesCollection = Nothing
   Dim sr As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Series = Nothing

   sc = c.SeriesCollection
   For i = 4 To sc.Count
       sr = sc.SeriesCollection(i)
       sr.AxisGroup = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary
   Next
   ```
3. Change Primary and Secondary Axis scale to fit as though the chart was separated. I change the primary axis scale from 0 to 1.6e7, and secondary axis scale from -7.0e7 to 7.0e7. At the same time, change display unit in millions, and remove all gridlines.

   ```
   Dim ax As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Axes
   Dim axpri As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Axis
   Dim axsec As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Axis

   ax = c.Axes
   axpri = ax.Item(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.XlAxisType.xlValue, _
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary)
   axsec = ax.Item(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.XlAxisType.xlValue, _
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary)
   axpri.MinimumScale = 0
   axpri.MaximumScale = 1.6e7
   axpri.DisplayUnit = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.XlDisplayUnit.xlMillions
   axpri.HasMajorGridlines = False
   axpri.HasMinorGridlines = False

   axsec.MinimumScale = -7.0e7
   axsec.MaximumScale = 7.0e7
   axsec.DisplayUnit = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.XlDisplayUnit.xlMillions
   axsec.HasMajorGridlines = False
   axsec.HasMinorGridlines = False
   ```
4. Change Primary and Secondary Axis number format so that each axis only show its own intended value. Primary Axis more than 8M will not be shown, and Secondary Axis less than 30M will not be shown.

   ```
   axpri.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "[<=8]0;;;"
   axsec.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "[>=30]0;;;"
   ```
5. Recolor series in Secondary Axis to match series in Primary Axis.

   ```
   Dim srPrev As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Series = Nothing

   For i = 4 To sc.Count
       sr = sc.SeriesCollection(i)
       srPrev = sc.SeriesCollection(i - 3)
       sr.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = srPrev.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
   Next
   ```
6. Delete Legend for `Column4`, `Column5`, and `Column6` for a seamless Chart Legend.

   ```
   c.Legend.LegendEntries(4).Delete()
   c.Legend.LegendEntries(5).Delete()
   c.Legend.LegendEntries(6).Delete()
   ```
7. [Optional] Add a neat color gradient for Data Points that exceed cut values.

   ```
   Dim p As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Point = Nothing

   p = c.SeriesCollection("June").Points("Paris")
   p.Format.Fill.TwoColorGradient(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoGradientStyle.msoGradientHorizontal, 1)
   p.Format.Fill.GradientAngle = 270
   p.Format.Fill.GradientStops.Insert(p.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB, 0.8)
   p.Format.Fill.GradientStops.Insert(p.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB, 0.97)

   p = c.SeriesCollection("May").Points("Madrid")
   p.Format.Fill.TwoColorGradient(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoGradientStyle.msoGradientHorizontal, 1)
   p.Format.Fill.GradientAngle = 270
   p.Format.Fill.GradientStops.Insert(p.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB, 0.8)
   p.Format.Fill.GradientStops.Insert(p.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB, 0.97)

   p = c.SeriesCollection("Column5").Points("Paris")
   p.Format.Fill.TwoColorGradient(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoGradientStyle.msoGradientHorizontal, 1)
   p.Format.Fill.GradientAngle = 90
   p.Format.Fill.GradientStops.Insert(p.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB, 0.7)
   p.Format.Fill.GradientStops.Insert(p.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB, 0.95)

   p = c.SeriesCollection("Column4").Points("Madrid")
   p.Format.Fill.TwoColorGradient(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoGradientStyle.msoGradientHorizontal, 1)
   p.Format.Fill.GradientAngle = 90
   p.Format.Fill.GradientStops.Insert(p.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB, 0.7)
   p.Format.Fill.GradientStops.Insert(p.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB, 0.95)
   ```
8. Voila! Hard work pays off, a broken y axis in PowerPoint chart.

[image]